# how to express finite set of finite sequences

Tags: notation

I want to define a finite set of finite sequences and they may have distinct cardinality. Is it correct to express this as follows:

Let $S=\{x_{n_{i}}: n=0,1,...,m \quad \text{and} \quad i=0,1,...,n_i\}$

I mean for a fixed $n$ we have a sequence of $i$ elements.

Comment: @Regret: That's my reading as well; perhaps you should post your comment as an answer. (Unfortunately I didn't see your comment until I'd posted, but if you post I'll delete my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Normally "double subscript" notation $n_{i}$ means you have a *function* $n$ of an index $i$, and $n_{i} = n(i)$, which seems not to be what you require.

It sounds as if you want *double indices*,
$$
S = \{x_{n, i}: i = 0, 1, \dots, i_{n},\ n = 0, 1, \dots, m\}.
$$
In longhand:
\begin{align*}
&x_{0,0}, x_{0,1}, \dots, x_{0,i_{0}}; \\
&x_{1,0}, x_{1,1}, \dots, x_{1,i_{1}}; \\
&\qquad \vdots \\
&x_{m,0}, x_{m,1}, \dots, x_{m,i_{m}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hmm, wait a minute. Wouldn't this be the set of all elements of all sequences? If the OP wishes for a set of all sequences, it would be along the lines of $$\left\{(x_{n,i})_{i=0}^{i_n}~\middle|~ n=0,1,\dots,m\right\}$$

Comment: @Regret: Yes, you're perfectly correct. :) I was matching the OP's notation. (It's not entirely clear the OP is distinguishing sequences from lists of elements, but I may have mis-gauged their intent.)